# Store a value for an aspx checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox list filled by a list of ListItem, each ListItem having both text and a value like "8" or "5".

But I realized that a CheckBox does not have a value, its value is checked or not.

```
var listType = SettingsManager.Get("CRMCaseTypes");
var listStatus = SettingsManager.Get("CRMStatusReasons");

var listTypeItems = ParseSettingList(listType);
var listStatusItems = ParseSettingList(listStatus);

cblCRMType.DataSource = listTypeItems;
cblCRMType.DataBind();
cblCRMStatus.DataSource = listStatusItems;
cblCRMStatus.DataBind();

foreach (Control c in cblCRMStatus.Controls)
{
   CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
   if(cb != null && cb.(value........)
}
```

Is there some way I could store a value in each checkbox and use it again in code behind after the user clicks submit?

Thanks

Comment: what class is `cblCRMStatus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can add a custom attribute to the `CheckBox`. You can use the HTML5 data attributes so your HTML will be HTML5 valid:

Set

```
foreach (Control c in cblCRMStatus.Controls)
{
   CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
   if(cb != null)
   {
       cb.Attributes.Add("data-MyField", myFieldVal);
   }
}
```

Retrieve

```
foreach (Control c in cblCRMStatus.Controls)
{
   CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
   if(cb != null && cb.Attributes["data-MyField"].ToString())
   {
       // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: How come when I databind I have no controls?

Comment: Can you post the ASPX for `cblCRMStatus`?

Answer (score 0):

How long do you want to re use it? If you want to store it temporarily, you can use session. If you want to store it longer, save it to a database or a file.

Comment: I basically am not interested in storing the Text, I'm interested in storing the Value foreach checked checkbox each time the user clicks submit... The text property is prone to duplicates...

The value is the ID of the status in the database...

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the value from the list that the checkboxes were bound to, referencing the relevant list item based on the index of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as an attribute -

SET:

```
myCheckBox.Attributes.Add("myKey","myValue");
```

GET:

```
var myKey = myCheckBox.Attributes["myKey"] != null ?  myCheckBox.Attributes["myKey"].ToString() : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there some way I could store a value in each checkbox and use it again in code behind after the user clicks submit?

You can set it to a Session

```
Session["CbxList"] = YourCheckBoxList;
```

Then when you want to reference it just add the following:

```
if (Session["CbxList"] != null)
{
YourCheckBoxList = Session["CbxList"] as CheckBoxList;
}
```

and use.

I've included a link to sessions in case you or anyone else is not familiar with them:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Items collection, not the Controls collection:

```
    foreach (ListItem item in cblCRMStatus.Items)
    {
        string value = item.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although probably no longer needed by OP I'll add my answer since this thread still ranks highly in Google. If this is an `ASPxCheckBox` you can make use of the `JSProperties` dictionary to store your value(s) like so:

```
cb.JSProperties["cpMyValue"] = "MyValue";
```

I would then usually use a callback from a `ASPxGridView` or `CallbackPanel` to get this back to server side (which is slightly out of scope of the original question).